# List of available translations in MediaWiki with Translate and ULS

Tags: translation, mediawiki

I created a wiki using mediawiki 1.28 and installed `Translate` & `UniveralLanguageSelector` extensions to create pages in two languages.
I need to create a list of available translations for current page (something like `interwiki` links of wikipedia)

How can i have a list of available translations of each page ?

Answer (score 1):

Put `<languages />` on top of the page. This is mentioned in the (admittedly somewhat sprawling) [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:Translate).